A simple minesweeper game's rule in propositional and first order logic
The following picture is a snapshot of a $3 \times 3$ minesweeper game environment.
According to the rules of the game, because of the middle 1, there is a mine in one of the other eight surrounding white squares.

I want to describe this rule in the propositional and the first order logic.
The following in my work:
Propositional logic:
definition:

$One_{i,j}$ : There is a 1 in $[i, j]$ location.
$M_{i,j}$ : There is a mine in $[i, j]$ location.

The rule:
$$
One_{2, 2} 
\Leftrightarrow (
      (      M_{1, 1} \land \lnot M_{1, 2} \land \lnot M_{1, 3} \land \lnot M_{2, 1} \land \lnot M_{2, 3} \land \lnot M_{3, 1} \land \lnot M_{3, 2} \land \lnot M_{3, 3}) \\ \lor (\lnot M_{1, 1} \land       M_{1, 2} \land \lnot M_{1, 3} \land \lnot M_{2, 1} \land \lnot M_{2, 3} \land \lnot M_{3, 1} \land \lnot M_{3, 2} \land \lnot M_{3, 3}) \\ \lor (\lnot M_{1, 1} \land \lnot M_{1, 2} \land       M_{1, 3} \land \lnot M_{2, 1} \land \lnot M_{2, 3} \land \lnot M_{3, 1} \land \lnot M_{3, 2} \land \lnot M_{3, 3}) \\ \lor (\lnot M_{1, 1} \land \lnot M_{1, 2} \land \lnot M_{1, 3} \land       M_{2, 1} \land \lnot M_{2, 3} \land \lnot M_{3, 1} \land \lnot M_{3, 2} \land \lnot M_{3, 3}) \\ \lor (\lnot M_{1, 1} \land \lnot M_{1, 2} \land \lnot M_{1, 3} \land \lnot M_{2, 1} \land       M_{2, 3} \land \lnot M_{3, 1} \land \lnot M_{3, 2} \land \lnot M_{3, 3}) \\ \lor (\lnot M_{1, 1} \land \lnot M_{1, 2} \land \lnot M_{1, 3} \land \lnot M_{2, 1} \land \lnot M_{2, 3} \land       M_{3, 1} \land \lnot M_{3, 2} \land \lnot M_{3, 3}) \\ \lor (\lnot M_{1, 1} \land \lnot M_{1, 2} \land \lnot M_{1, 3} \land \lnot M_{2, 1} \land \lnot M_{2, 3} \land \lnot M_{3, 1} \land       M_{3, 2} \land \lnot M_{3, 3}) \\ \lor (\lnot M_{1, 1} \land \lnot M_{1, 2} \land \lnot M_{1, 3} \land \lnot M_{2, 1} \land \lnot M_{2, 3} \land \lnot M_{3, 1} \land \lnot M_{3, 2} \land       M_{3, 3})
$$
First order logic
Definition:

$One_{i,j}$ : There is a 1 in $[i, j]$ location.
$M_{i,j}$ : There is a mine in $[i, j]$ location.
$
\forall x, y, a, b \quad Adjacent([x, y], [a, b]) \Leftrightarrow
((x = a-1 \lor x =a \lor x=a+1)  \land (y = b − 1 \lor y = b + 1)) \lor (y = b \land (x = a − 1 \lor x = a + 1))
$

The rule:
$$
One_{2,2} \Leftrightarrow \exists a, b  \quad Adjacent([2, 2], [a, b]) \land M_{a, b} \land ((\forall x, y \quad Adjacent([2, 2], [x, y]) \land M_{x, y}) \Rightarrow (x = a \land y = b)) 
$$
Are my obtained answers correct?
